# Расчет даты по unix time

Tags: php, unixtimestamp

как мне рассчитать дату по unix метке(нужно для постов). Например, определяем - `1438340119` - и результат — `вчера в 15:00`. И вообще, как все это делается?

Comment: Вам нужна разница с текущим временем или все же перевод unixtime в дату вида 12.11.2011 12:35:56?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция из форума FluxBB. Убрал зависимости из кода

```
<?php
// $timestamp - время в секундах по Гривничу
// $diff - смещение в секундах от Гривнича (для разных юзеров разные часовые пояса)
// $date_only - возвращаем только дату без времени
// $date_format - формат вывода даты
// $time_format - формат вывода времени
// $time_only - возвращаем только время без даты
// $no_text - не преобразовываем дату в текст Сегодня Вчера
function format_time($timestamp, $diff = 0, $date_only = false, $date_format = 'd M Y', $time_format = 'H:i:s', $time_only = false, $no_text = false)
{
    if ($timestamp == '')
        return 'Никогда';

    $timestamp += $diff;
    $now = time();

    $date = gmdate($date_format, $timestamp);
    $today = gmdate($date_format, $now+$diff);
    $yesterday = gmdate($date_format, $now+$diff-86400);

    if(!$no_text)
    {
        if ($date == $today)
            $date = 'Сегодня';
        else if ($date == $yesterday)
            $date = 'Вчера';
    }

    if ($date_only)
        return $date;
    else if ($time_only)
        return gmdate($time_format, $timestamp);
    else
        return $date.' '.gmdate($time_format, $timestamp);
}
```

Comment: а почему эта функция показывает на 3 часа раньше?

Comment: $diff задайте для смещения в секундах.

Answer (score 1):

Используем функцию PHP localtime

array localtime ([ int $timestamp = time() [, bool $is_associative = false ]]