# Не могу правильно сделать сегодня и вчера через php

Tags: php

Не могу правильно сделать сегодня и вчера через php. Как можно сказать, запись добавлено `вчера в 15:00` и сегодня я смотрю в 11:00 он показывает `сегодня в 15:00`. Проблема в ~24

```
<?php
function timestamp($time) {
    $time_difference = time() - $time;
    $hours = round($time_difference / 3600 );
    $days = round($time_difference / 86400 );
    if ($hours<=24) {
        if($hours==1){
            echo "час назад";
        } else if($hours>1){
            echo "сегодня".', '.date('H:i', $time);
        }
    } else if ($days<=7) {
        if ($days==1) {
            echo "вчера".', '.date('H:i', $time);
        }
    }
}
echo timestamp('1444924170');
?>
```

Comment: т.е. дата сбрасывается на текущую?

Comment: @Александр да точно!!!

Comment: Решение есть в этом http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439235/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-unix-time вопросе.

Comment: @Visman спасибо но как поставить коды в этом коде. Чета там не понятно

Comment: @KYRAN, в начале функции расписаны все параметры. Что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: @Visman  у меня написан все коды так и уже все готовь и просто чуть-чуть исправить а не полностью заменить коды `$minutes = round($time_difference / 60 );
    $hours = round($time_difference / 3600 );
    $days = round($time_difference / 86400 );
    $months = round($time_difference / 2419200 );
    $years = round($time_difference / 29030400 );`

Comment: @KYRAN, раз вы хотите использовать свою функцию, значит вопрос не ко мне.

Comment: Если хотите чисто свою функцию использовать с правками - то это будут сильный костыли. Кстати, вам нужно еще учесть тот факт, что `вчера` может быть днем `воскресенье` а сейчас `понедельник`. А еще тот факт, что к примеру я написал сообщение `1 января в 23:59:00`, а на дворе `2 января 01:00:00` и по факту это будет уже вчера. Хотя это меньше 24. Но всё упирается скорее не в 24, а вообще в целом надо переделать)

Comment: Относительное время - зло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем предлагаю сделать вот так:

```
function timestamp($time) { 
    $postDate = date('d.m.Y', $time);
    $postTime = date('G:i', $time);
    $diff = time() - $time;

    if ($diff < 3600) {
        return "в течение часа";
    } elseif (date('d.m.Y') == $postDate) {
        return "сегодня в " . $postTime;
    } elseif (date("d.m.Y", strtotime("-1 day")) == $postDate) {
        return "вчера в " . $postTime;
    } else {
        return $postDate . " в " . $postTime;        
    }   
}

echo timestamp(1445058000);
```

Потому, что с вашими `24` слишком как-то не совсем все понятно.

Например, если кто-то опубликует 1 июля в 23:00:00, а на дворе будет 2 июля 01:00:00 то у вас будет показывать `Сегодня`. Или если кто-то опубликует 1 июля в 23:59:00, а на дворе будет 2 июля 23:58:00  все еще будет сегодня. Согласитесь это бредово.

Берите вариант выше и подредактируйте под себя.

Comment: Спасибо за понимание!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте просто сравнивать две даты.

```
if ($date1<$date2)
{
  echo "вчера".', '.date('H:i', $time);
}
```

Только при сравнении нужно, чтобы обе даты были в одном и том же формате. Подробнее об этом можно почитать [тут](http://webgyry.info/compare-two-dates).

Comment: Спасибо но это не пойдет

Comment: По-моему, по ссылке бред. Точнее, там не договаривается, в каком именно формате они должны быть.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите проверку на равно и всё будет нормально

```
if ($hours<24) {
```

Ведь 24 это уже сутки (завтра/вчера), а, например, 23:59 ещё сегодня